# Standardize Firstname and Lastname in Access SQL

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Hope you are all having fun in stack-overflow.

I have three columns FirstName , LastName and FullName.

Now, I have to update FullName which needs to be standardize.

For suppose there are some agents who shuffled FirstName with LastName and vice-versa while booking tickets. to identify those records and standardize FullName

Following picture will help you to understand better than what I am saying.

How can I update that FullName using SQL in Access. ( Provide solutions for other platforms like MySQL and SQL Server I could manage to implement those in Access )

Thanks in Advance !!

[image: Standardize Name]

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "standardize"?  Should `FullName` be assumed to be the correct arrangement?

Comment: FullName is the correct arrangment which I have to update using SQL

Comment: How do you know which record has the correct first/last name?

Comment: so far, I am just going by headings mentioned Firstname as Firstname , lastname as lastname.  Atleast the output will be 70-80 percent accurate. If I can go that way..

Comment: Is `Vishnu` a firstname or the lastname? How would we know? How would we be able to tell the database? OR are you more concerned with just rectifying those two records as one and we should just pick one randomly to be the firstname and then assume that for any matching record?

Comment: Yes, you can pick randomly either vishnu or karthink and assume them as your fiirstname and rectify those two records as one..

Comment: Lookup SQL concatenate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm.. I think this is valid Access syntax:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET FULLNAME = (SELECT MAX(T2.FULLNAME)
                FROM yourTable T2
                WHERE yourTable.FIRSTNAME = T2.LASTNAME
                AND   yourTable.LASTNAME = T2.FIRSTNAME
                OR   (yourTable.FIRSTNAME = T2.FIRSTNAME
                AND   yourTable.LASTNAME = T2.LASTNAME))
```

This will just choose one of the possible `FullName` values for any mismatches, but that sounds like what you want based on your comments.

[Fiddle example using SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/72119/1/0)

Comment: Thanks Aaron !! Subquery in access update queries won't work. I make changes to your query. It worked for me..

Comment: @HarshaVardhan Cool, glad it helped you get there at least